# How to add new row to Datatable on ajax Success without reloading page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using datatables and adding some data in table on ajax response, i want to add new row in talbe on ajax success without reloading the page to view the row added.
Here is my table row

```
            <tr id="prod_tbl_row<?=$product->id ?>">    

            <td> <?=$product->product_title ?></td>
            <td> <?=$product->product_desc ?></td>
            <td> <?=$catName ?></td>
            <td> 
            <img src="<?=$location ?>" style="width:50px;height:50px;" />
            </td>
            
            <td> 
        
            <i id="<?=$product->id ?>" class="fa fa-trash remProductsBtn" > </i></td>
            
        </tr>
```

Here is ajax success

```
           success: function(data) 
        {
```

jq("#Html").html(data.text);

```
    alert(data.text);
    jq('#new_<?=$formName ?>_tbl').dataTable().fnAddData( [
       data.title,
       data.desc,
       data.img, 
       data.cat,
            ] );
                                                     
            }
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, Please check this link  https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: thanks for reply. I have checked this link but not find an appropriate answer for my question. I am new to ajax and stuck in this issue from too many hours.

Comment: Hav you found any solution

Comment: no bro stikll stucked